# Delphi IDE - Access violation in module 'rtl70.bpl'

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have and old AV that hunts me. It appears randomly (often but not always) when I switch between projects (close current project and double click a different DPR file to load it) or when I close Delphi (7). So it appears daily but not that offten and I can live with it. 
However, in the last few days it started to be really annoying.

Any idea where I could start?
Here is the log for this AV:

```
Application:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1.2 Name/Description: delphi32.exe - (Delphi-32 Development Environment)
  1.3 Version Number  : 7.0.8.1
  1.4 Parameters      : /np
  1.6 Up Time         : 10 seconds

Exception:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2.2 Address       : 40005F50
  2.3 Module Name   : rtl70.bpl - (Borland Component Package)
  2.4 Module Version: 7.0.8.1
  2.5 Type          : EAccessViolation
  2.6 Message       : Access violation at address 40005F50 in module 'rtl70.bpl'. Read of address 04B0E854.

Computer:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  5.1 Name          : Spanu
  5.2 Total Memory  : 3060 Mb
  5.3 Free Memory   : 2285 Mb
  5.4 Total Disk    : 465.75 Gb
  5.7 Processor     : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 430  @ 2.27GHz
  5.8 Display Mode  : 1680 x 945, 32 bit
  5.9 Display DPI   : 96
  5.10 Video Card   : NVIDIA GeForce GTS 360M (driver 6.14.11.9716 - RAM 1024 MB)
  5.11 Printer      : 

Operating System:
------------------------------------
  6.1 Type    : Microsoft Windows XP
  6.2 Build # : 2600
  6.3 Update  : Service Pack 3


Call Stack Information:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Address |Module         |Unit                 |Class         |Procedure/Method             |Line|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|*Exception Thread: ID=2940; Priority=0; Class=; [Main]                                          |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|40005F50|rtl70.bpl      |System.pas           |TObject       |InheritsFrom                 |    |
|7C903247|ntdll.dll      |                     |              |RtlConvertUlongToLargeInteger|    |
|7C90E485|ntdll.dll      |                     |              |KiUserApcDispatcher          |    |
|7C910451|ntdll.dll      |                     |              |RtlReleasePebLock            |    |
|77F643DB|SHLWAPI.dll    |                     |              |SHRegGetValueW               |    |
|77F643E8|SHLWAPI.dll    |                     |              |SHRegGetValueW               |    |
|40005F48|rtl70.bpl      |System.pas           |              |_FindDynaClass               |    |
|4002E5F1|rtl70.bpl      |Classes.pas          |              |ActivateClassGroup           |    |
|4002E5C0|rtl70.bpl      |Classes.pas          |              |ActivateClassGroup           |    |
|0036224B|designide70.bpl|Componentdesigner.pas|TComponentRoot|CreateFromStream             |    |
|003621BC|designide70.bpl|Componentdesigner.pas|TComponentRoot|CreateFromStream             |    |
|0036544C|designide70.bpl|Componentdesigner.pas|TComponentRoot|Resurrect                    |    |
|00551378|coreide70.bpl  |Modules.pas          |TUnitModule   |Show                         |    |
|00512D3C|coreide70.bpl  |Docmodul.pas         |TFilterList   |OpenFile                     |    |
|00512C9C|coreide70.bpl  |Docmodul.pas         |TFilterList   |OpenFile                     |    |
|005145E7|coreide70.bpl  |Docmodul.pas         |              |CallDefaultOpenProc          |    |
|005145BC|coreide70.bpl  |Docmodul.pas         |              |CallDefaultOpenProc          |    |
|00831A98|vcl70.bpl      |Controls.pas         |TControl      |WndProc                      |    |
|00856D3C|vcl70.bpl      |Forms.pas            |TApplication  |DispatchAction               |    |
|00831910|vcl70.bpl      |Controls.pas         |TControl      |WndProc                      |    |
|00834B40|vcl70.bpl      |Controls.pas         |TWinControl   |WndProc                      |    |
|00834914|vcl70.bpl      |Controls.pas         |TWinControl   |MainWndProc                  |    |
|400469B4|rtl70.bpl      |Contnrs.pas          |TObjectList   |First                        |    |
|40046B72|rtl70.bpl      |Contnrs.pas          |TComponentList|GetItems                     |    |
|4002F684|rtl70.bpl      |Classes.pas          |TList         |IndexOf                      |    |
|400469C8|rtl70.bpl      |Contnrs.pas          |TObjectList   |IndexOf                      |    |
|7E4196C2|user32.dll     |                     |              |DispatchMessageA             |    |
|7E4196B8|user32.dll     |                     |              |DispatchMessageA             |    |
|00855608|vcl70.bpl      |Forms.pas            |TApplication  |ProcessMessage               |    |
|008556C2|vcl70.bpl      |Forms.pas            |TApplication  |HandleMessage                |    |
|008556B8|vcl70.bpl      |Forms.pas            |TApplication  |ProcessMessages              |    |
|0085585C|vcl70.bpl      |Forms.pas            |TApplication  |Run                          |    |
|7C90DCB8|ntdll.dll      |                     |              |ZwSetInformationThread       |    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Modules Information:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Handle  |Name                           |Description                                                                   |Version         |Size    |Modified           |Path                                                                                                |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|00340000|designide70.bpl                |Borland IDE Designer Package                                                  |7.0.8.1         |625664  |2004-04-23 07:01:00|C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|003E0000|BRCIDE.DLL                     |RC Compiler Interface                                                         |7.0.4.453       |78848   |2002-08-20 08:38:52|C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|00400000|delphi32.exe                   |Delphi-32 Development Environment                                             |7.0.8.1         |545792  |2004-04-23 07:01:00|C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|00490000|coreide70.bpl                  |Core Integrated Development Environment                                       |7.0.8.1         |3186688 |2010-04-28 06:46:56|C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|007B0000|vcl70.bpl                      |Borland Component Package                                                     |7.0.8.1         |1383936 |2004-04-23 07:01:00|C:\WINDOWS\system32                                                                                 |
|00910000|vclactnband70.bpl              |Borland Component Package                                                     |7.0.4.453       |276480  |2002-08-20 08:40:28|C:\WINDOWS\system32                                                                                 |
|00960000|vclide70.bpl                   |Integrated Development Environment Specific Components                        |7.0.4.453       |708608  |2002-08-20 08:38:56|C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|00A20000|tlib70.bpl                     |Borland Type Library Exporter                                                 |7.0.8.1         |486912  |2004-04-23 07:01:00|C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|00AA0000|dcc70.dll                      |                                                                              |7.0.8.1         |843264  |2004-04-23 07:01:00|C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|00BF0000|delphide70.bpl                 |Core Delphi Integrated Development Environment                                |7.0.4.453       |473088  |2002-08-20 08:38:54|C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|00CF0000|ad4IDESpellToold7.bpl          |                                                                              |1.0.0.0         |39424   |2009-01-22 06:43:34|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Projects\Bpl                                                       |
|00D20000|borlndmm.dll                   |Borland Memory Manager                                                        |7.0.4.453       |22528   |2002-08-20 08:38:52|C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|01DA0000|iTchHk.dll                     |iTouch Hook Library                                                           |1.0.0.0         |4608    |2002-11-22 23:15:00|C:\Program Files\Logitech\iTouch                                                                    |
|02000000|stride70.bpl                   |String Resource Editor IDE Package                                            |7.0.4.453       |93696   |2002-08-20 08:38:56|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|02020000|proide70.bpl                   |Core Professional Integrated Development Environment                          |7.0.4.453       |848896  |2002-08-20 08:38:56|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|02100000|delphipro70.bpl                |Delphi Professional Integrated Development Environment                        |7.0.4.453       |357376  |2002-08-20 08:38:54|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|02160000|designdgm70.bpl                |Borland IDE Diagram Package                                                   |7.0.4.453       |424960  |2002-08-20 08:38:54|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|021D0000|direct70.bpl                   |Developer Direct News Module                                                  |7.0.4.453       |105984  |2002-08-20 08:38:54|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|021F0000|Normaliz.dll                   |Unicode Normalization DLL                                                     |6.0.5441.0      |23552   |2009-01-07 18:20:36|C:\WINDOWS\system32                                                         |7.0.4.453       |167424  |2002-08-20 08:38:56|C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|02480000|htmlide70.bpl                  |HTML Integrated Development Environment Package                               |7.0.4.453       |178688  |2002-08-20 08:38:54|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|024B0000|webdsnap70.bpl                 |Borland Web Midas Components                                                  |7.0.4.453       |268288  |2002-08-20 08:40:30|C:\WINDOWS\system32                                                                                 |
|02500000|dbrtl70.bpl                    |Borland Database Component Package                                            |7.0.8.1         |258560  |2004-04-23 07:01:00|C:\WINDOWS\system32                                                                                 |
|02550000|inetdb70.bpl                   |Borland Internet DB Component Package                                         |7.0.4.453       |37888   |2002-08-20 08:40:24|C:\WINDOWS\system32                                                                                 |
|02560000|PDIFac70.bpl                   |                                                                              |1.0.0.0         |22528   |2003-12-30 06:06:00|c:\PROGRAM FILES\BORLAND\DELPHI7\Bin                                                                |
|025B0000|DFWEDIT.DLL                    |                                                                              |                |99872   |2002-08-20 08:38:54|C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|02C50000|DelphiSpeedUp7.dll             |                                                                              |2.7.8.0         |115712  |2009-11-30 16:27:22|C:\Documents and Settings\olai\Application Data\DelphiSpeedUp                                       |
|02C80000|GExpertsD7.dll                 |GExperts for Delphi 7                                                         |1.3.2.0         |2280960 |2007-09-08 23:02:02|c:\Program Files\Borland\Tools\GExperts                                                             |
|03560000|vcldb70.bpl                    |Borland Database Component Package                                            |7.0.8.1         |264704  |2004-04-23 07:01:00|C:\WINDOWS\system32                                                                                 |
|035B0000|dclstd70.bpl                   |Borland Standard Components                                                   |7.0.4.453       |311808  |2002-08-20 08:38:54|C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|03600000|dclemacsedit70.bpl             |Borland EMACS Keybindings Example Package                                     |7.0.4.453       |42496   |2002-08-20 08:38:54|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|03610000|dclmlwiz70.bpl                 |IDE Wizards for Markup Languages                                              |7.0.4.453       |32256   |2002-08-20 08:38:54|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|03620000|dclshlctrls70.bpl              |Borland Win32 Shell Controls                                                  |1.0.0.0         |32256   |2002-08-20 08:38:54|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|03630000|vclshlctrls70.bpl              |Borland Win32 Shell Controls                                                  |1.0.0.0         |90624   |2002-08-20 08:40:28|C:\WINDOWS\system32                                                                                 |
|03650000|bdertl70.bpl                   |Borland BDE DB Component Package                                              |7.0.4.453       |222208  |2002-08-20 08:40:22|C:\WINDOWS\system32                                                |                                                                              |1.0.0.0         |423936  |2002-08-20 08:40:24|C:\WINDOWS\system32                                                                                 |
|03760000|IntrawebDB_50_70.bpl           |                                                                              |1.0.0.0         |92672   |2002-08-20 08:40:24|C:\WINDOWS\system32                                                                                 |
|03840000|DragDropD7.bpl                 |                                                                              |                |292352  |2010-06-14 22:25:36|c:\MyProjects\Packages\DragDrop\Library\Delphi 7                                                    |
|038C0000|CommonPackages_D7.bpl          |                                                                              |2.222.2.19      |605696  |2010-08-19 18:34:08|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Projects\Bpl                                                       |
|039E0000|ExceptionExpert7.bpl           |                                                                              |1.0.0.0         |1346560 |2010-02-25 16:38:46|c:\Program Files\Borland\Tools\EurekaLog\Delphi7                                                    |
|04050000|BorDebug.dll                   |Borland debugger dll                                                          |5.0.16.13       |89088   |2008-02-05 14:13:20|c:\Program Files\Borland\Tools\EurekaLog                                                            |
|04070000|GR32_D7.bpl                    |                                                                              |1.0.0.0         |374784  |2010-05-08 04:19:34|c:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl                                                       |
|04100000|GR32_DSGN_D7.bpl               |                                                                              |1.0.0.0         |69632   |2010-05-08 04:19:34|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Projects\Bpl                                                       |
|04120000|dclmcn70.bpl                   |Borland Midas Components                                                      |7.0.4.453       |54272   |2002-08-09 06:00:00|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|04140000|DCLIB70.bpl                    |Interbase Express Design Package                                              |7.0.4.453       |181248  |2002-08-20 08:38:54|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|04180000|soaprtl70.bpl                  |Borland SOAP Runtime Support                                                  |7.0.4.453       |528384  |2002-08-20 08:40:26|C:\WINDOWS\system32                                                                                 |
|04210000|dbx70.bpl                      |Borland Database Explorer UI & engine package                                 |7.0.4.258       |611328  |2002-08-20 08:38:52|C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|042C0000|OverbyteIcsDel70.bpl           |                                                                              |1.0.0.0         |1003008 |2009-05-03 10:02:06|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Projects\Bpl                                                       |
|043D0000|XmlComponents_D6_D7.bpl        |                                                                              |                |49664   |2009-09-20 05:25:24|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Projects\Bpl                                                       |
|043F0000|EmbeddedWebBrowser_D7.bpl      |                                                                              |                |2155520 |2010-02-07 04:42:54|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Projects\Bpl                                                       |
|04690000|teedb70.bpl                    |Borland TeeChart DB Component Package                                         |7.0.4.453       |43520   |2002-08-20 08:40:26|C:\WINDOWS\system32                                                                                 |
|057E0000|Amhooker.dll                   |Amhooker                                                                      |7.80.0.4        |36864   |2007-02-10 13:17:28|C:\WINDOWS\system32                                                                                 |
|06740000|RLINK32.DLL                    |                                                                              |4.0.10.10       |59904   |2002-08-20 08:38:56|C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|10000000|PowerMenuHook.dll                                                        |
|40A40000|tee70.bpl                      |Borland TeeChart Component Package                                            |7.0.4.453       |371712  |2002-08-20 08:40:26|C:\WINDOWS\system32                                                                                 |
|40AA0000|teeui70.bpl                    |Borland TeeChart UI Package                                                   |7.0.4.453       |254976  |2002-08-20 08:40:26|C:\WINDOWS\system32                                                                                 |
|40BB0000|inetdbbde70.bpl                |Borland Internet DB BDE Component Package                                     |7.0.4.453       |16384   |2002-08-20 08:40:24|C:\WINDOWS\system32                                                                                 |
|40BC0000|inetdbxpress70.bpl             |Borland Internet DBxpress Component Package                                   |7.0.4.453       |16384   |2002-08-20 08:40:24|C:\WINDOWS\system32                                                                                 |
|48000000|Jcl70.bpl                      |JEDI Code Library RTL package                                                 |2.1.1.3536      |2392064 |2010-06-20 11:28:00|C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl                                                       |
|48400000|JclVcl70.bpl                   |JEDI Code Library VCL package                                                 |2.1.1.3536      |173056                                                    |
|503B0000|dclwbm70.bpl                   |Borland Web Midas Components Designers                                        |7.0.4.453       |167936  |2002-08-20 08:38:54|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|503E0000|dclie70.bpl                    |Delphi-32 Development Environment                                             |7.0.4.453       |15872   |2002-08-20 08:38:54|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|503F0000|dclwebsnap70.bpl               |Borland WebSnap Design Package                                                |6.0.0.0         |298496  |2002-08-20 08:38:54|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|50440000|dclocx70.bpl                   |Borland Sample Imported ActiveX Controls                                      |7.0.4.453       |162816  |2002-08-20 08:38:54|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|50550000|dclsmp70.bpl                   |Delphi Sample Components                                                      |7.0.0.188       |17920   |2002-08-20 08:38:54|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Bin                                                                |
|508B0000|dclofficexp70.bpl              |Borland Sample ActiveX Server Components                                      |7.0.1.569       |2512896 |2002-08-20 08:38:54|c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Bin                                                                |

|038A0000|JclDebugExpert70.bpl           |JCL Debug IDE extension                                                       |2.1.1.3536      |78336   |2010-06-20 11:28:02|c:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl                                                       |
|58000000|JclBaseExpert70.bpl            |JCL Package containing common units for JCL Experts                           |2.1.1.3536      |123392  |2010-06-20 11:28:00|c:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl                                                       |
|58040000|JclFavoriteFoldersExpert70.bpl |JCL Open and Save IDE dialogs with favorite folders                           |2.1.1.3536      |27136   |2010-06-20 11:28:02|c:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl                                                       |
|58060000|JclProjectAnalysisExpert70.bpl |JCL Project Analyzer                                                          |2.1.1.3536      |69120   |2010-06-20 11:28:02|c:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl                                                       |
|58080000|JclSIMDViewExpert70.bpl        |JCL Debug Window of XMM registers                                             |2.1.1.3536      |101376  |2010-06-20 11:28:04|c:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl                                                       |
|580C0000|JclUsesExpert70.bpl            |JCL Uses Wizard                                                               |2.1.1.3536      |68608   |2010-06-20 11:28:02|c:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl                                                       |
|58100000|JclRepositoryExpert70.bpl      |JCL Package containing repository wizards                                     |2.1.1.3536      |97280   |2010-06-20 11:28:02|c:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl                                                       |
|58120000|JclStackTraceViewerExpert70.bpl|JCL Stack Trace Viewer                                                        |2.1.1.3536      |122880  |2010-06-20 11:28:04|c:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Assembler Information:
--------------------------------------------------------------
; System.TObject.InheritsFrom 
; ----------------------------
40005F4A  mov     eax, [eax]
40005F4C  cmp     eax, edx
40005F4E  jz      System.TObject.InheritsFrom
40005F50  mov     eax, [eax-$24]               ; <-- EXCEPTION
40005F53  test    eax, eax
40005F55  jnz     System.TObject.InheritsFrom
40005F57  ret

Registers:
-----------------------------
EAX: ????       EDI: ????    
EBX: ????       ESI: ????    
ECX: ????       ESP: ????    
EDX: ????       EIP: ????    

Stack:               Memory Dump:
------------------   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
0013F69C: 0013FE00   40005F50: 8B 40 DC 85 C0 75 F3 C3 B0 01 C3 90 51 83 C0 C4  .@...u......Q...
0013F6A0: 03A54D66   40005F60: 8B 00 89 04 24 8B 04 24 5A C3 8B C0 B8 FF FF 00  ....$..$Z.......
0013F6A4: 0013F6C8   40005F70: 80 C3 8B C0 C3 8D 40 00 C3 8D 40 00 C3 8D 40 00  ......@...@...@.
0013F6A8: 01D49A78   40005F80: 56 66 8B 32 66 09 F6 74 17 66 81 FE 00 C0 73 10  Vf.2f..t.f....s.
0013F6AC: 01C91560   40005F90: 50 8B 00 E8 08 F6 C4 C2 58 74 05 89 F1 5E FF E1  P.......Xt...^..
0013F6B0: 00000000   40005FA0: 5E 8B 08 FF 61 F0 C3 90 53 56 57 31 C9 31 FF 8A  ^...a...SVW1.1..
0013F6B4: 00000000   40005FB0: 1A EB 02 8B 00 8B 70 CC 85 F6 74 15 66 8B 3E 83  ......p...t.f.>.
0013F6B8: 00000000   40005FC0: C6 02 8A 4E 06 38 D9 74 15 66 8B 0E 01 CE 4F 75  ...N.8.t.f....Ou
0013F6BC: 00000000   40005FD0: F1 8B 40 DC 85 C0 75 DB EB 18 8A 1A EB EB B5 00  ..@...u.........
0013F6C0: 00000000   40005FE0: 8A 5C 31 06 32 1C 11 80 E3 DF 75 EE 49 75 F1 8B  .\1.2.....u.Iu..
0013F6C4: 00000000   40005FF0: 46 02 5F 5E 5B C3 8B C0 53 56 57 89 CF 31 DB 31  F._^[...SVW..1.1
0013F6C8: 0013FE1C   40006000: C9 EB 02 8B 00 8B 70 CC 85 F6 74 13 66 8B 0E 83  ......p...t.f...
0013F6CC: 008559C3   40006010: C6 02 3B 56 02 74 13 66 8B 1E 01 DE 49 75 F3 8B  ..;V.t.f....Iu..
0013F6D0: 00000000   40006020: 40 DC 85 C0 75 DD 88 07 EB 0A 83 C6 06 31 C9 8A  @...u........1..
0013F6D4: 00834945   40006030: 0E 41 F3 A4 5F 5E 5B C3 53 56 57 31 C9 31 FF 8A  .A.._^[.SVW1.1..
0013F6D8: 00834954   40006040: 1A 50 8B 00 8B 70 C8 85 F6 74 14 66 8B 3E 83 C6  .P...p...t.f.>..
```

Edit:
StackOverflow does not allow me to paste here the entire log, so not all loaded libraries are shown.
Can anybody make any sense from the Call Stack section. Usually it points to the exact location of the problem, but now it doesn't really tell anything concrete.

Edit:
I uninstalled ALL (and I really mean ALL) experts and external programs from IDE and I still have the AV. Now it appears in a different context, more exactly when I move the mouse above a variable and the tooltip (code insight) pops up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the problem:
In one control I was freeing (on Destroy) an object that was created something like this:

```
MyFoultyControl:= Create(AOwner);
MyFoultyControl.Parent:= ACowner;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have CnPack installed ? Or another Delphi IDE enhancer ?

My problems started when I installed CnPack (otherwise a great product - woulnd't work without it).

When the error is received the editor part becomes read only (right click the editor to verify this in the popup menu).

Comment: The OP's dump shows the GExperts and JCL/JVCL are loaded - but not CnWizards.

Comment: @Fabricio - JCL/JVCL were left behind after an unsuccessful Jedi uninstall. I manually removed all JEDI BPLs and now it works. But I rearranged also some other packages (not removed, just changed the dependencies). So, I hope the fix was from removing JEDI (I don't like it) and it will stay.

Comment: I have the CnPack on my drive. I just wanted to install it and trial it. Hmmm... should I do it anymore?    Anyway, I agree with you that the AV is cause by one of my many IDE enhancements.

Comment: @Altar I was a GExperts user before I discovered CnPack. Now I just use CnPack - but both have their merits, just for me, I don't miss GExperts.

Answer (score 0):

I started seeing this bug after I installed Glary Utilities.  It's the only program that I have using Borland Delphi 7.0. (rtl70.bpl).  Not sure why they have a hook on shift right mouse click in explorer (maybe they send info to NSA or Billy) but it prevented getting a context menu (to get to 'Copy as Path').  After Glary Utils crashed the right click function returned to normal.